# IOS: How do I enable react-native fetch to work when Cellular Data is turned on and Wi-Fi is off?

Tags: ios, xcode, react-native, https

I have built an app in react-native and I used the fetch function to retrieve data from our HTTPS server.  After building the app and loading it on the physical iPhone 12 Max the app works fine when the Wi-Fi is turned on.  However, when the Wi-Fi is turned off (out of our office network) the Cellular Data is sued and it is turned on.   In this mode I  received a 'TypeError: Network request failed] error and the app cannot seem to retrieve our data.  z

I do have the info.plist setting to allow http and https connections even thoug I only use https for the app.  Any ideas what I need to do in the info.plist or the code itself to get this to work?

The fetch code snippet:

```
await fetch(urldb)
   .then( ( response) => response.text())
   .then( async (textResponse) => {
    myList = textResponse.match(/[A-Za-z0-9%\-'(),,!?&;#:]+\.(jpeg|jpg|png)/ig);
    for(let i=0; i <  myList.length; i++) {
       keyID = myList[i];
       keyID = keyID.replace(/%20/g, "");
       keyID = keyID.toLowerCase();
       keyID = keyID.replace(/\.(jpeg|jpg|png)/, "");
       keyID = keyID.replace(/\(/g, "");
       keyID = keyID.replace(/\)/g, "");
       keyID = keyID.replace(/,/g, "");
       keyID = keyID.replace(/'/g, "");
       keyID = keyID.replace(/\./g, "");
       keyID = keyID.replace(/%3f/g, "?");
       keyID = keyID.replace(/%23/g, "");
       keyID = keyID.replace(/&amp;/g, "&");
       myFNArray = keyID.split("-");
       keyID = keyID.replace(/-/g, "");
       if(myFNArray.length == 2) {
          if(myFNArray[1] !== "artwork") {listHash[myFNArray[1]] = urldb + myList[i];};
          if(myFNArray[0] !== "artwork") {listHash[myFNArray[0]] = urldb + myList[i];};
       };
       listHash[keyID] = urldb  + myList[i];
   };
})
.catch((error) => {
   /* .. Error Catching routines later */
   console.error( "getListHash: Error ", error);
    return
});
```

Comment: Is your server accessible from outside of your wifi network?  E.g. Can you access it with Safari vis 4g?  There is no special permission to use 4g.  You can deny your app permission to use 4g via settings, but this something you would need to do deliberately

Comment: Hi Thanks for taking a look at this issue.  Yes,  the server is hosting by asura  and it is avalable over the internet.   We tested  the server is accessable around the world:  See: http://rockitstudios.com/troprock/logo/  as just one open folder on the server.

Comment: Did you test it from Safari on the phone itself via 4G?  Can you provide the specific error code you are getting?

Comment: You nailed the missing link.  I had all the testers switch to cellular data mode on Android and iOS.  The safari / browers were not able to get to the Asura Hosting servers with the web address.  Only when they're on wi-Fi.  Our testors are scattered around the US and on different Wi-Fi networks.   So it seems the servers aren't configured to be Cellular Data network ready 00 We are in discussion with the server support team for resolution.  I think I need to ppst the resolution here when it is resolved.   Thanks tfor the tip.

Comment: Thanks for your tip!   It was indeed not working even during the iphone browsing to the webaddress under Cellular Data network.    After discussing this with our hosting provider, they found the issue that they did not enable  the service to allow CCellular Data network access.

Answer (score 0):

After using the browser on the device with cellular data netowrk enabled, it was clear that our hosting service did not have theCellular Data network access enabled.   The serivce provider resolved the issue after filing the ticket on the issue.  Nothing was wrong with my code...